# Is there such a thing as universal path finder code in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am doing a cleanup project at work for reports of applications that are being used.

Here is the first part of the project where I need the new workbook to pick up the extracted excel reports from a folder, copy a particular worksheet (via input message box) change the worksheet name to reflect the application report and paste it in the new workbook.

As this macro workbook will be shared with my other colleagues, I would like it to have a "select path directory" box for them to pick and choose the path directory.

I have done the basics of point the macro directly to a specific location to pick the files. My manager wants it to be able to choose the path directory if another colleague uses this same template.

We have team Google drive which is where the files are stored, so if the code is able to extract the files from the team drive instead of the user downloading onto their system will be great.

```
Sub CopySheets()

    Dim path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim whichSheet As String

    path = "/Users/timothy.wong/Downloads/Project Clean Up/2019/"
    FileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")
    whichSheet = InputBox("Which month would you like to copy? Enter month (eg. Jan, Feb, Mar)")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True
        Sheets(whichSheet).Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Workbooks(FileName).Close
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(FileName, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", FileName) - 1)
        FileName = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

The basic code works well, I need to make it a little more advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopySheets()

    Dim path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim whichSheet As String
    Dim SheetNames As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    path = GetFolder
    If path = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No folder was selected. Ending the procedure."
        End
    End If
    FileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsx")
    whichSheet = InputBox("Which month would you like to copy? Enter month (eg. Jan, Feb, Mar)")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Len(wb.Sheets(whichSheet).Name) = 0 Then 'Here we handle an error on the inputname for the sheet.
        On Error GoTo 0
            SheetNames = GetSheetNames(wb)
            MsgBox "The input sheet does not exist in this workbook. The current worksheet names are: " & SheetNames
            whichSheet = InputBox("Which month would you like to copy? Enter month (eg. Jan, Feb, Mar)")
        End If
        With wb.Sheets(whichSheet)
            .Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            .Close
        End With
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = Left(FileName, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", FileName) - 1)
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Selecciona una carpeta"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing

End Function
Function GetSheetNames(wb As Workbook) As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        GetSheetNames = GetSheetNames & ", " & ws.Name
    Next ws

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I just gave it a try but, I'm having a compile error: Argument not optional pointing to "GetSheetsNames" with "Sub CopySheets()" highlighted.

Comment: My bad... `SheetNames = GetSheetNames(wb)` fix that

Comment: It is now a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set", and it's pointing to ".Title = "Selecciona una carpeta""

Comment: @TimothyWong There is no way that gives you an error. Just above that line is the `With fldr`

Comment: Do I need to do anything else? Or the code is good to use in a new workbook and run? Sorry, for my many questions as I'm still very new to VBA excel.

Comment: I've amended your code deleting innecesary steps and improving it. There is no need for libraries or anything else. It should work fine just like that. You may change the "selecciona la carpeta" for "select the folder" and thats it.

Comment: Thank you Damian for your help :)

Comment: Hi it's Timothy here again, I did some Googling around on the internet about the error "run-time error '91' object variable or with block variable not set excel for mac" on the line ".Title = "Selecciona una carpeta". Could this be due to the Mac/Win environments that is causing this error? It seems like this is a common issue, currently, i'm on Excel for Mac ver. 16.24.